# How to register this tablet to Ubuntu udev list?

Tags: android, android-emulator, device-driver, adb

I've got a cheap android tablet and I need to use it to test apps on it. I am using Ubuntu so I first have to add the device to `udev` list.

I connected the tablet, but `adb` does not see it

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

The I tried using `lsusb`, but the device is not identified to the Ubuntu (USB debugging is checked! in tablet's properties)

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:0928 Logitech, Inc. QuickCam Express
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c517 Logitech, Inc. LX710 Cordless Desktop Laser
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2207:0000
```

If I attach my mobile phone, I see that it is connected via the last channel. So, I assumed that this tablet is identified as `ID 2207:0000`, thus making ID Vendor "2207". I edited udev file `51-android.rules` to look like this

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2207", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Restarted the comp, reattached USB cable to the tablet, the the tablet **was not recognized again**.

Any advise of what should I do? How to make this tablet be visible to the `adb`?

**EDIT**

Does this vendor id looks odd to you: 2207:0000? Especially those four zeroes?

Comment: Looks like a lot of "cheap devices" identify themselves as `2207:****`. One of them being _BSNL Penta/Pantel tablets_. (Added keywords to help other struggling users in their web search).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all those having a tablet with ID 2207, these 2 links made it be visible.

First one is [this one](http://clamel.netai.net/smartpad850i/enable_adb) (`http://clamel.netai.net/smartpad850i/enable_adb`).

It will help you set such device up. If after this setup the tablet appears as `???????`, then use the other link to make it visible.

The other link is [here](http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html) (`http://ptspts.blogspot.com/2011/10/how-to-fix-adb-no-permissions-error-on.html`).

**If after system restart you lose the settings**, then either repeat the same steps or simply restart `udev` service.

Comment: Thanks a million, followed the instructions and everything went well

Answer (score 17):

I had same problem as you, what i done:
Added vendor id to ~/.android/adb_usb.ini

```
echo "0x2207" >>~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

Added the following lines to /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", 
ENV{PRODUCT}=="207/*", MODE="0666" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="207", MODE="0666"
```

After making the above changes, restart the `adb` server and check the device again.

```
adb kill-server  // kill the adb server if it is running
adb start-server  // Restarts the adb server
adb devices  // It will list all connected devices
```

Now my chinese tablet Archos c906 is recognize on ./adb device as:

```
List of devices attached 
0123456789ABCDEF    device
```

Comment: adb_usb.ini fix works on Windows too, but on Windows the file probably doesn't exist (so just make a new one)

Comment: For anyone getting "stuck" trying the adb_usb.ini fix --- VERIFY the vendor ID for your particular device, and use that in place of "2207"!

Answer (score 2):

some time you have to add it adb.ini (yes, even on linux) as well - I wrote this post for the kindle fire - but it should work for you too.

http://sentinelweb.co.uk/connecting-kindle-fire-to-adb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: added to the file `adb_usb.ini` this content: `echo "0x2207" >>~/.android/adb_usb.ini echo "0x0000" >>~/.android/adb_usb.ini`, restarted adb, but the device is still not visible. :(