# USB Vendor ID for DATAWIND by UBISLATE

Tags: android

I am trying to run and debug my application on the device  DATAWIND by UBISLATE.

How can I find the USB Vendor ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of  Vendor IDs is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds) it seems that the device you specified does't has one.
So you can not connect to Android Debug Bridge (adb), still you can copy the apk from bin folder of your project to your device, install and run it.

Comment: Thank you Arun C, I need to adjust my views on the specified device too, my view is rendering properly in samsung S3, galaxy tab, etc, Not in Datawind. So every time, I need to send my apk file to device for checking views, No other way, Right?

Answer (score 5):

To connect the Android Debug Bridge (adb) with DATAWIND Ubislate 7C+, run a command in Ubuntu terminal

```
lsusb
```

it will list the connected usb's as

```
......
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 18d1:0003 Google Inc. 
......
```

in which 18d1 is to be taken as the vendor id. Then edit the /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules as follows

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"
```

then restart the udev by

```
# /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

That's it, It is done now. Have to disconnect and reconnect the tablet with computer. 
For a check type in the terminal as

```
adb shell
```

it will points to the root of tablet as `root@android:/`

or `type

```
adb devices
```

that gives

```
List of devices attached 
200804111413fc082   device
```

This is based on

[How to register this tablet to Ubuntu udev list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111005/how-to-register-this-tablet-to-ubuntu-udev-list)

and the link provided in it.

http://clamel.netai.net/smartpad850i/enable_adb

Comment: Great!. This worked for me in a mac changing the lsusb comand for:system_profiler SPUSBDataType and following the steps in: http://www.tekkie.ro/mobile-development/osx-list-usb-devices-lsusb-equivalent/

Comment: Similarly this works for OSX by using "About This Mac" => "More Info" => "System Report" then using the adb_usb.ini file like this: "echo 0x2207 >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini" (That code is accurate for my ubislate)

Answer (score 0):

USB vendor ids can be found at www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids.
18d1  Google Inc.